# How to cast Field to specified type

Tags: java, swing, reflection

I'm trying to make an user interface using Swing, but I don't want to have to manually include every component in my component array.

So far the best attempt I got throws an exception, which I can't really have.

```java
for (Field f : this.getClass().getFields()) {
    if (f.getType().isAssignableFrom(JComponent.class)) {
        JComponent field = (JComponent) f.get(JComponent.class);
        components.add(field);
    }
}
```

I wanted the code I showcased to not include any exception, but it does.
Is there any way to do this without having the risk of an exception?

Comment: I get the `IllegalAccessException`

Comment: George Z. is right:  You really should not use reflection.  You are giving up all kinds of correctness checks performed by the compiler, and runtime optimizations performed by the JVM.  Furthermore, I’m pretty sure your UI will look awful, since the only LayoutManagers that meaningfully allow addition of multiple components with no constraints are FlowLayout, GridLayout, and BoxLayout (and OverlayLayout, which is irrelevant).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`reflect`ion usage should not be used when it is not necessarily required. Most of the times, the reason of creating a `component` is to add it in a container. Once it is added there, you can easily ask them from the container using `Container#getComponents` method.

Check this example:

```
JButton loadButton = new JButton("load");
JButton saveButton = new JButton("save");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.add(loadButton);
panel.add(saveButton);
for (Component component : panel.getComponents()) {
    // ...
}
```

In order to give you more help, you will have to tell us what do you want to do with this array. I mean, where do you want to use it?

---

If you insist of using it though, the `for` should be:

```
for (Field f : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
    if (JComponent.class.isAssignableFrom(f.getType())) {
        JComponent field = (JComponent) f.get(this);
        components.add(field);
    }
}
```

Comment: Reflection code is still invalid tho: as it should be `f.get(this)` or some other instance. + it might be nice to add safe check to ensure that field is not static. As currently you are still trying to get a Field from instance of different class than it is declared in.